# How to display value option from dropdown list in Elgg

Tags: php, elgg

Elgg is build on the MVC framework. My main agenda is to be able to save the value selected from the dropdown list, after which is to then display the chosen value the item listing.  The following code is actually constructed in PHP that is following the Elgg framework closely.

What I have managed to do is to make use of the existing Elgg framework to display the dropdown list. In which, the dropdown list is created by the creation of a form in the following directory: mod/plugin/views/default/forms/plugin/form.php. I have hence made use of the existing Elgg framework (input/dropdown)to create my dropdown list as a form.

Secondly, I have managed to save the values chosen in the dropdown list and display the value in a success message. This is done in the action directory which will allow the values to be saved into the database when user clicks on 'save' button.

Code for saving and displaying value:

```
<?php
/** 
* Elgg options uploader/submit action 
*  
* @package ElggFile 
*/


// get the input variables
$list = get_input('OptionItems');
$container_guid = (int) get_input('container_guid', 0);
if ($container_guid == 0)
{
    $container_guid = elgg_get_logged_in_user_guid();             
}
$my_select_guid = (int) get_input (file_guid);

//create a new my_select object
$my_select = new ElggObject();
$my_select -> dropdown = $list;
$my_select ->container_guid = $container_guid;


//save to database and get id of the new my_blog
$my_select_guid = $my_select->save();


if($my_select_guid){
    system_message("Your action post = " . $list);
    //to add new muy_select object to river
    add_to_river('river/object/file/create', 'create', elgg_get_logged_in_user_guid(), $list->guid);
}
else{
    register_error("Your action post is not saved");
}
```

However, at this point, I am stuck in displaying the chosen value of the dropdown list as an extended view, within the view/default/object/file/
How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's all in Elgg documentation about the views that I linked for you before: http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.12/guides/views.html#extending-views